# Differential Equation Separation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I having trouble solving this diffeq.

$$\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t} = \frac{(r(t) - B)}{z} \cdot P(t) + c\cdot w$$

,where $c\cdot w$ is a constant. Normally I would just separate but I do not think I can do that here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal method for solving $$\frac{dP}{dt} = g(t)P(t) + k$$ where $k$ is a constant and $g(t)$ is any function of $t$, is to put all $P(t)$ on the same side and multiply as such:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dP}{dt} - g(t)P(t) &=& K\\
e^{\int^t-g(s)ds}\frac{dP}{dt} - g(t)e^{\int^t-g(s)ds}P(t) &=& Ke^{\int^t-g(s)ds}\\
\frac{d}{dt}\Big(e^{-\int^t g(s)ds}P(t)\Big) &=& Ke^{\int^t-g(s)ds}
\end{eqnarray*}

Then integrate both sides and divide by the exponential to isolate $P(t)$.

Comment: Could you do this but more specifically for my problem? I also have other constants and not just g(t)

Comment: The reason I am confused is because of the g(s)ds and how to integrate that. I am not sure where this s came from. Can you show me an example of how you integrate this?

Comment: $s$ is just a dummy variable, nothing else. $g(t)$ is any function which multiplies $P(t)$ so here it's your $\frac{r(t) - B}{z}$. I can't do it for you, it depends on your function $r(t)$.